# how to change edittext font size

Tags: android, android-edittext, font-size

i wrote a code to make a drop down list which have some items "8" , "12" , "13" ... etc 
 xml like this :

```
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/spinner"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
```

now i have an edittext in the same layout which have this tag :

```
  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/etFName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" >
  <requestFocus />
  </EditText>
```

what i want is when i select 8 for example the edittext font size will be 8 and when i select 12 the edittext font size will be 12 and so on ....

here is my Graduation.java code

```
    private Spinner spinner;
private static final String[]paths = {"item 1", "item 2", "item 3"};
 EditText etFName;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.graduation);
    /*spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String>adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>  (Graduation.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,paths);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener((OnItemSelectedListener) this);*/
    Spinner dropdown = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    String[] items = new String[]{"8", "12", "16", "18", "20", "24", "28"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
    dropdown.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    // Whatever you want to happen when the first item gets selected
                    break;
                case 1:
                    // Whatever you want to happen when the second item gets selected
                    break;
                case 2:
                    // Whatever you want to happen when the thrid item gets selected
                    break;

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }
    });
```

how should i fill the comments lines ??

Comment: `EditText#setTextSize`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should try this (I didn't):

```
int fontSizeInt;
try
{
    fontSizeInt = Integer.parseInt(items[position]);
}
catch (NumberFormatException e)
{
    fontSizeInt = 12; // Default size.
}
etFName.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, (float) fontSizeInt);
```

Note `int` being cast to `float`. Keep in mind, you don't want to let NumberFormatException catch you off guard, however safe you feel.

Answer (score 0):

```
etFName.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,Integer.parseInt(items[position]));
```

Comment: No - the items are supposed to be working in the same way, so switch is not needed here